# is it good to add index on column used in group by clause?

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, indexing, query-optimization

I have a query like-

```
SELECT x, SUM(y)
FROM xyz 
WHERE z>=100 
GROUP BY x
ORDER BY SUM(y) DESC;
```

will it be faster if I am going to add index on x?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only but also z,

```
ADD INDEX (z, x)
```

when there is composite index, column order is important. in you case, 'z' is compared to 100 firstly.

this like provides useful information about it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html

and, MySQL has explained about GROUP BY Optimization http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-optimization.html

Comment: composite means this index gonna work for both or only z and not for x. What if i am going to make two different index say on z and x? Because i have other queries which compare x to some values in that case this index will not work.

Comment: @Aamir0731 then you need two indexes, INDEX(x), INDEX(z, x). It looks like redundant. but needs for speed.